# C++ integer wont change

Tags: c++

I am an absolute C++ novice it seems so i need some help.
I am trying to make a programm which determines the least amount of coins needed to pay for something.

Example: You tell it you want to pay for 2,50 so it says you need a 2€ coin and 0.50€ coin (instead of something like: you need 5 * 0.50€ coins)

So my approach was to give it the price so then it will run a while loop for each coin testing whether the coin still fits the Value.
My Problem is that i cannot change my integers at all and im pretty sure its some really simple mistake i just cant figure out.

Code (Just the Function that calculates):

```
int Rechner() {

int Betrag;

int ZweiEuro = 0;
int EinEuro = 0;
int FuenfzigCent = 0;
int ZwanzigCent = 0;
int ZehnCent = 0;
int FuenfCent = 0;
int ZweiCent = 0;
int EinCent = 0;


cin >> Betrag;
cout << "Die kleinse Menga an Muenzen um ihren Betrag zu bezahlen ist:" << endl << endl << endl;




ZweiEuro + 2;







cout << "2.00 = " << ZweiEuro << endl;
cout << "1.00 = " << EinEuro << endl;
cout << "0.50 = " << FuenfzigCent << endl;
cout << "0.20 = " << ZwanzigCent << endl;
cout << "0.10 = " << ZehnCent << endl;
cout << "0.05 = " << FuenfCent << endl;
cout << "0.02 = " << ZweiCent << endl;
cout << "0.01 = " << EinCent << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;


cout << "[Enter] druecken um zu beenden.";

cin.sync();
cin.get();
return 0;
```

So this doesnt have any while loops because they dont work just like the ZweiEuro + 2 doesnt change anything.
The Result always stays 0 whether I add something or not.

Im pretty sure i can finish this programm easily if i get behind changing the god damn values of my Variables.
Thanks for help.

Comment: `ZweiEuro + 2;` produces a result but you do not store it. You need to assign the result to a variable. Try `ZweiEuro = ZweiEuro + 2;` or `ZweiEuro += 2;`.

Comment: it is just like in the initializations that you got right: `ZweiEuro = 0;`, there you also didnt just write `0` and expected the compiler to know what to do with that value ;)

Comment: Here's a riddle: Say out loud "two more 2€ coins than what I'm holding in my left hand". How much money are you now holding in your left hand?

Comment: 1) use english names for variables/functions... 2) use the highest compiler warning. This helps you a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats not how its done. Both of these should work:

```
ZweiEuro = ZweiEuro + 2;
ZweiEuro += 2;
```

Thats the way if you want to increment it.
You could also just assign it the 2 as long as you dont want to loop it or anything

```
ZweiEuro = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the integer. By writing `ZweiEuro + 2;`  you don to change ZweiEuro value. You should write `ZweiEuro = ZweiEuro + 2; or ZweiEuro += 2;` instead, which means that ZweiEuro would be ZweiEuro value plus two. This is just the syntax of c++. You will get used to it soon.